# Integration test using both WithServer and Server.forRouter

Tags: playframework, integration-testing

I'm writing an Integration test by extending the class **"play.test.WithServer"**.
This is for testing an API in my Play service. My API sends a GET request to a different external service for retrieving data. 
I don't want to send the GET request during integration tests, so I'm trying to create a mock external service using **"Server.forRouter()"**.

When the mock service is running, the actual **testServer** which is started by the **WithServer** class does not run. There are no errors or exceptions. I only get a ConnectException while connecting to the **testServer**.

This issue occurs only when I'm creating a mock service using Server.forRouter() along with **WithServer**.

Reference:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFunctionalTest
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTestingWebServiceClients

Sample code for reproduction:

```
public class HomeControllerIntegrationTest extends WithServer {

private Server server;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Logger.error("mock server");
    WSClient ws = WS.newClient(-1);
    CompletionStage<WSResponse> response = ws.url("http://localhost:" + server.httpPort() + "/hello").get();
    Logger.error("response mock server = " + response.toCompletableFuture().get().getBody());


    Logger.error("my test server");
    ws = WS.newClient(-1);
    response = ws.url("http://localhost:" + testServer.port() + "/status").get();
    Logger.error("response test server = " + response.toCompletableFuture().get().getBody());
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Logger.error("before");
    server = Server.forRouter(new RoutingDsl()
            .GET("/hello").routeTo(() -> ok("Hello world"))
            .build(), Mode.TEST, 20000);
}

}
```